# Dynamically set Django settings variables from Database

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-settings

I am currently trying to build an application that manages multiple databases. Since the app will be managing data in 30+ databases I am attempting to generate DATABASE_ROUTERS in the settings file. I cannot directly import the db model into the settings file. I get this error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

This error makes since. Is there a way I can control the sequence of events so that I have access to the database before all of the settings are established on execution? My goal is to automate database connections pulling relevant data from a DB and generate the DATABASE_ROUTERS and DATABASES within the setting file. Is this even possible? Is there a package that I can download that does exactly this?

If you do not know what I am asking please do not down vote just ask me to elaborate.

Comment: Unfortunately django settings are immutable at runtime. My next question is the database that holds the DATABASE configs in a django database?

Comment: yes the configs will be held in the apps default database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. file init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51081783/django-core-exceptions-appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet-file-init)

Comment: You can look at my answer, it may be of interest, https://stackoverflow.com/a/51082877/7692463

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to query the data I needed from my database and import it into the settings file. I created the script below. Keep in mind this can be improved, this is just something I modified from [here](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/sqlite-python-select/). This directly queries data from my test db (sqlite3). I use postgreSQL in production. This script should work, with some modification, with PostgreSQL.

As you can see below I am storing the data in dictionaries that is then stored in a list. I then import that list of dictionaries into my settings file. From there I can loop through the list and create my DATABASE_ROUTERS and DATABASES dynamically from the database. I was also able to generate router Classes in my routers.py file by importing the same list. Please comment below if you need me to elaborate further.

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
dbs = []

def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by the db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return None


def select_all_data(conn):
    """
    Query all rows in the table
    :param conn: the Connection object
    :return:
    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM fund_table")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print(row)


def select_name_and_db(conn):
    """
    Query table by fund_name and db_name
    :param conn: the Connection object
    :return:
    """
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT fund_name, db_name FROM fund_table")

    rows = cur.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        dbs.append({"fund_name": row[0], "db_name": row[1]})
    return dbs


def main():
    database = "edb.sqlite3"

    # create a database connection
    conn = create_connection(database)
    with conn:

        """ select_all_data(conn) """
        select_name_and_db(conn)

main()
```

Comment: Thanks. This trick helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make one function that loads this variables and make it async, so after you app is ready you load it, but im not sure is this will work properly

https://hackernoon.com/asynchronous-python-45df84b82434

**Dirty Sollution** is make 1 file for each BD and you call your settings based in what BD gonna work...

Comment: I will try this out and get back to you. Thanks.